# Is there any way to change compression type of TMX file?

Tags: tiled

Basically it's all in the title, you can choose compression type then you create new tile map, but after it's done the "Save As..." option doesn't provide compression type selection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change it in the map properties. (Map -> Properties...)

Comment: Oh, how could I possibly overlook it, I definetly looked in map properties.. Thanks for great tool!